# Can i convert my android app xml files to adobe xD file?

Tags: xml, android-layout, adobe-xd

I know that I can export adobe xD designs into XML files but I need to know that can I do the reverse thing like I already have XML layouts, now can I convert those into adobe-xD wire-frames without drawing manually?

here is a sample XML code which I want to convert to adobe xD wireframe without manually drawing, can I do that and how if yes?

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view_assign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view_delivery_point_codes"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="15dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:background="@drawable/exp_del_merch_list_custom_back_three"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2345-A1-A2"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/pointcode"
        android:layout_below="@id/orderID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/exp_del_orders_list_custom_back_one"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="Merchant Name: "
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMerchantName"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <View
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_20"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="Merchant Outlet: "
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMerchantOutlet"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <View
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_20"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:text="Customer info"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="3dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="Customer Name: "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCustName"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="Customer Address: "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCustAddress"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="Customer Phone: "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCustPhone"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_20"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reassignEmployee"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/exp_del_merch_list_custom_back_three"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/orderID"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Re-assign"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_next_24dp"
            android:drawableTint="@color/white"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are workflows for designer-developer.
But you can't convert it by any plugin.
For now you have to draw it manually.